# ¿Como calcular valores utilizando la inyección de dependencia en un ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con ASP.NET MVC usando Visual Studio 2017 aplicando el enfoque de Code First. Tengo tres clases (tablas) en el modelo, una es un repositorio llamado DataBase y una interfaz IDataBase. Estoy almacenando datos en la memoria sin usar db. 
Esta es mi clase "FacturadeArticulo"

```
public class FacturadeArticulo   {
public int ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> InvoiceID { get; set; }
public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string ArticleDescription { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> PricePerUnit { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> TaxPercentage { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> NettoAmount { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> BruttoAmount { get; set; }

public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }}
```

Mi pregunta es: Como puedo calcular los valores en esta Classe:
(Quantity*PricePerUnit =NettoAmount) y ((PricePerUnit * TaxPercentage) / 100 + PricePerUnit*Quantity=BruttoAmount). ¿Es esto posible?
Repositorio DataBase:

```
public class DataBase:IDataBase{   
private static List<Supplier> suppliers = new List<Supplier>();
private static List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice>();
private static List<FacturadeArticulo> facturadeArticulos = new List<FacturadeArticulo>();

private static int _nextId = 1;

public DataBase()
{     
}
public FacturadeArticulo Add(FacturadeArticulo item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    }
    // TO DO : Code to save record into database 
    item.ID = _nextId++;
    facturadeArticulos.Add(item);
    return item;
} public IEnumerable<FacturadeArticulo> getAll()
{    
    return facturadeArticulos;
}
```

Comment: estas seguro que la cantidad el precio unitario pueden ser un dato null ? debeeria ser obligatorios

Answer (score 1):

Podrias definir la propiedad como la formula que describes

```
public Nullable<decimal> NettoAmount { 
   get{
       if(this.Quantity == null || this.PricePerUnit == null)
          return null;

       return this.Quantity.Value * this.PricePerUnit.Value; 
   }
}



public Nullable<decimal> NettoAmount { 
   get{
       if(this.Quantity == null 
           || this.PricePerUnit == null 
           || this.TaxPercentage == null)
          return null;

       return ((this.PricePerUnit.Value * this.TaxPercentage.Value) / 100 + this.PricePerUnit.Value * this.Quantity.Value); 
   }
}
```

como veras son propiedades `get` ya que solo podras obtener el resultado, son de solo lectura